# How to make && as logical operator in string

Tags: java, arrays, string, java-6

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class ListString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        List list=new ArrayList();
        list.add("Patter1 -> Assert1");
        list.add("Patter2 -> Assert2");
        list.add("Patter3 -> Assert3");
        list.add("Patter4 -> Assert4");
        list.add("Patter5 -> Assert5");


        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {


            String string = (String)list.get(i);    
            System.out.println(string);
            StringBuffer stringAppended=new StringBuffer();
            String[] split = string.split(" -> ");
            for (int k = 0; k < split.length; k++) {
                stringAppended.append(split[k]).append(" && ");
                //  System.out.println(split[k]);
            }
            stringAppended.replace(stringAppended.length() - 3, stringAppended.length(), " ");
             System.out.println(stringAppended);

            if(string.contains(stringAppended)){

                System.out.println("INSIDE IF LOOP");

            }

        }

    }

}
```

In the above code I am trying to check **Patter1** and **Assert1** are present in the stringPath, String path has below pattern

```
Patter1 -> Assert1
Patter2 -> Assert2
Patter3 -> Assert3
Patter4 -> Assert4
Patter5 -> Assert5
```

I am trying to do this by below code

```
if(stringPath.contains(stringAppended)){

                System.out.println("INSIDE IF LOOP");

            }
```

I am doing dynamic application where stringAppended will have **Patter1 && Assert1** , stringAppended will have more && like this in my application, 
How can we make && as the logical operator here, Currently it is treating as normal string

Comment: Don't use *raw* generics. Change to `List<String> list=new ArrayList<>();`. That way you won't need to cast to `String`. --- Also, why not use an enhanced `for` loop, also known as a for-each loop?

Comment: If it is always the &&-Operator you don't need it. You could append the Strings to a list and write a function that checks the the string against the whole list.

If you really need to be dynamic, you could think about using the Nashorn javascript-engine

Answer (score 1):

Building a string with `&&` in it will not magically turn it into an expression that can be evaluated. It is still just a string with text.

If you have a list of words and need to check if an input text contains *all* those words, you have to do two things:

- Loop through the words and check them one at a time.
- Make sure you only match "words", e.g. if word is `is`, you don't want to match `this`.
- *(optional)* Match words case-insensitively, e.g. word `This` also matches `this`.

To do all that, using regular expression would be the easiest, e.g.

```
public static boolean containsAllWords(String input, List<String> words) {
    for (String word : words) {
        String regex = "(?i)\\b(?:" + Pattern.quote(word) + ")\\b";
        if (! Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input).find())
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(containsAllWords("This was a test.", Arrays.asList("was", "test")));
System.out.println(containsAllWords("This was a test.", Arrays.asList("is", "test")));
```

*Output*

```
true
false
```

Answer (score 0):

Split it into two boolean expressions:

`if(stringPath.contains("Patter1") && stringPath.contains("Assert1" )){ ... }`

Comment: stringAppended will be dynamic it is dynamic and have && with in that